# Java translation of groovy spread operator

Tags: groovy, groovy-spread

Given:

```
class Car {
    String make
    String model
}
def cars = [
       new Car(make: 'Peugeot', model: '508'),
       new Car(make: 'Renault', model: 'Clio')]     

def makes = cars*.make
```

How does `cars*.make` works behind the scene in java? Does it create a new Map object in the heap and combine two maps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a look at the bytecode, and the only maps involved are the maps that are created to initialize the `Car` objects.

Once the two car objects are initialized, they are put into a list. The spread operator translates (in this case) to a call to [`ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getPropertySpreadSafe`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ScriptBytecodeAdapter.html#getPropertySpreadSafe(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)).

Looking at the source of that method, you'll see that it basically just creates a new `ArrayList` and adds the requested property (in this case `make`) of each object:

```
public static Object More ...getPropertySpreadSafe(Class senderClass, Object receiver, String messageName) throws Throwable {
    if (receiver == null) return null;

    List answer = new ArrayList();
    for (Iterator it = InvokerHelper.asIterator(receiver); it.hasNext();) {
        answer.add(getPropertySafe(senderClass, it.next(), messageName));
    }
    return answer;
}
```